# git: Reset Repository into a Clean State

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to "reset" a repository into a clean state. Hold up! Before you say

- just use `git-clean`
- ... or `git-reset`

this is not what I am looking for! I don't want to reset files, but state. That means, aborting all in-progress operations like rebases, merges, bisect, and removing any auxiliary files like `MERGE_HEAD` or `MERGE_MSG` inside the `.git` directory itself.

I could do it manually of course with a series of commands, but I was hoping for something more elegant that doesn't require me to know what state the repo currently is in.

Comment: Thats actually the question. I'm looking for a method that wouldn't require me to know what operation / state it is currently in. Meaning, regardless if it is an interactive rebase, merge, bisect or whatnot. It should work in any case.

Comment: I got it.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: `git reset` will abort an ongoing merge, but not an ongoing sequencer operation (multi-commit cherry-pick, or revert, or rebase). Your best bet is to query for ongoing operations first, then use a more explicit `--abort` on whichever one(s) you want to end.

Comment: This is a great idea. `git abort --all` would be very welcome!

Comment: I have written my own, here - https://github.com/lassevk/GitToolbox/blob/master/git-abort - as far as I know there isn't anything built into git.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the scripts provided in git/contrib : [`git-completion.bash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) contains a `__git_ps1` function which will scan the different files in the `.git` folder to build a message stating `REBASE ...`, `MERGE ...` etc ...

You could use that to run the correct `--abort` command.

It's the closest thing to a git command that I know of which indicates what action is currently taking place.

You can also look into the code of this function, and see the list of checks it does to determine if it is in a merge state, or a rebase, or a cherry-pick.